# In shell script, how do you check if the number of arguments is not 2 or 3

Tags: shell

I have a shell script which needs to run when the number of arguments is NOT 2 OR 3.

This is what I have tried but it is not working.

```
elif [ $# -ne 2 ] || [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
```

I am using bash.

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: "and" is `&&` not `||`. Well, the first title matched better. The sentence: "no. of arguments is not 2 or no. of arguments is not 3" will always be true.

Comment: Thank you for correction. Yes, below works.
elif [[ $# -ne 2 && $# -ne 3 ]] ; then

Comment: You can also use the arithmetic conditional: `elif (( $# != 2 && $# != 3 ))`